# Как получить список запущенных процессов в системе?

Tags: python, python-2.x

Мне нужно получить список запущенных процессов в системе, затем проверить есть ли в этом списке например "foo.exe", варианты с subprocess не предлагать (т.к я когда в pyinstaller указываю --noconsole(мне нужен этот параметр) то потом приложение не запускается).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import psutil # pip install psutil
proc_name = 'foo.exe'
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name() == proc_name:
        print "Process {}  started".format(proc_name)
```